# Xpath in XML with break line or symbol ","

Tags: xml, xpath

in my xml :

```
<test>
   <a id="bk1"/>
   <b id="bk2"/>
</test>
```

using this following xpath:

```
/child::test/child::a/@id
```

the result return

```
bk1bk2
```

expected output

```
bk1
bk2
```

or

```
bk1,bk2
```

isn't possible to do this?

Comment: The XPath expression returns a nodelist, not a single string. What language do you use to wrap around XPath?

Comment: sqlplus. so it's not possible?

Comment: You simply can't return it as a scalar value. You must return it as a node, a XmlType in sqlplus.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
`string-join(/child::test/child::a/@id, ',')`

Note that you probably misspelled your src XML because it is invalid (unclosed tags) and you have only one tag `<a>` in it.

EDIT:
based on your previous comment I assume you need a solution for Oracle (PL/)SQL. This could be a way to go:

```
select t.*
    from xmltable('for $t in $d/test return <t>{fn:string-join($t/a/@id, ",")}</t>'
              passing xmltype('<test><a id="bk1"/><a id="bk2"/></test>') as "d"
              columns "ids" varchar2(256) path '/t'
          ) t
```

Comment: Without more information about your environment and errors you are getting I'm not able to proceed further to help you.